# Implementing a stack of objects in a class without importing the built-in Stack class

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, stack, implementation

I'm confused with what my homework assignment is asking. Any help is appreciated.

It says "Create a new class, in a separate file named ImageStack.java. This class must implement a stack of objects (whose type is something for you to figure out), and you must not import the built-in Stack class, but rather you will utilize the ArrayList class to hold the elements of your image stack."

A little background about this homework assignment is that I am using ImageStack.java with another .java class file (ImageStack.java will be working with the other file). ImageStack has methods: `push(), pop(), peek(), isEmpty(), clear(), getSize()`. I know how to do all of these, but I'm just not sure how to "implement" the stack thru an ArrayList, if that's what it's actually asking.

So I understand, it is telling us to not use `import java.util.*;` In my CS classes, I've seen the word "implement" mean different things... I'm not sure if I should start this class file like

```
public class ImageStack {
```

or

```
 public class ImageStack implements...
```

or if implements means to literally just create the Stack in a field or something like:

```
private Stack<Integer> .....
```

Any pseudo-code, or code suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Show us what code have you done?

Comment: Did you read about [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ? just use built-in function in this class to implement a stack

Comment: Pham, I'm kind of confused, what code would I write to implement the stack? There isn't any mention of stacks on that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Implement a stack" isn't using Java terminology here; it just means to write a class that does what a stack is supposed to do.  You don't have to use the `implements` keyword in your answer at all.  What you're going to do is use an `ArrayList` to hold the elements that are currently on the stack.

I think your conclusion that you can't use `import java.util.*` is wrong.  Basically you're just not supposed to use the built-in `Stack` class.  Using `import` with a wildcard like this doesn't actually import every class in `java.util` into your program, it just makes them available so that you can use the classes by name without putting `java.util.` in front of the name.  However, if you don't want to use this import, you can get `ArrayList` by saying `import java.util.ArrayList;`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. I'm still kind of confused how I go about using an ArrayList to hold the elements that are currently on the stack. B/c usually I implement a stack like Stack<E> example =  new Stack<E>(); where does the ArrayList come into play?

Comment: @eltigre Do you know how to use the methods of an `ArrayList`?  If not, start by reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  Once you've gotten familiar with what methods you can use on an `ArrayList`, imagine how you would represent the stack data as elements of an `ArrayList`, then work out what `ArrayList` methods would change the stack in the way you want when you push or pop from the stack.

Comment: Ok I think I get what you're saying. You're saying that I don't actually create a Stack by doing something like ... "Stack<E> example = new Stack<E>();". Instead, I create an ArrayList and then use it as I would a stack? It's been a while since my last CS class, so my terminology is a bit rusty. Thanks!

Comment: @eltigre Yes, that's what they want you to do.  You're writing your own `ImageStack` class that uses an `ArrayList` as you would use a stack.  Then other classes can use `ImageStack` the same way they would use a different stack class, using the `push` and `pop` methods that your `ImageStack` provides.

Comment: Thank you for all the help and clear explanations. I think I know what to do now.